# C++: Problems of file write using FILE Library when file beat process is running

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a code for file write using FILE Library, and usually works, but I found a case where doesn't work: When the code runs concurrently with filebeat process.

I don't know this cause of the problem because my c++ project does not support debugging mode.

I am participating in an open source project developed by someone else and i am not familiar with this project yet.

This is my c++ code:

```
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("log_path.c_str()", "w");

if (fptr == NULL) 
{
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
}

fprintf(fptr, "%s", log.c_str());
fclose(fptr);
```

Is there a any other good way to save log files?

Please give me some advice.

Comment: "Concurrently" meaning "threads"?

Comment: Do you really want the filename to be *literally* `"log_path.c_str()"`?

Comment: I'm guessing `"log_path.c_str()"` should be `log_path.c_str()` and log_path is a std::string?

Comment: yes, log_path is std::string like a "test.txt". Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: I made some modifications to make the real file location invisible in log_path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have broken-pipe exception when you try to write a file.

This exception occurs when a c++ code try to write a log file while the filebeat software is reading the log file.

So, I recommend using this C++ code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

logFilePath = "this is path string of log file";
log = "this is log string";

ofstream output(logFilePath, ios::app);
output << log << endl;
output.close();
```

This code that used the offstream library will be solve the broken pipe exception.

If you use this c++ code, it is able to use string type for file write process, so it's not necessary to type convert via c_str().

I checked that this code able to used with File beat 7.10.0.

Thank you.

Comment: It helps to include types here, either `const char*` or `std::string`.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. This is perfectly work. and thank you tadman.